# What do anonymous Class/Structs/Unions inside a Class/Struct/Union mean?

Tags: c++, anonymous-class

I was looking at the bgfx source code and i found this?

I know what an anonymouse class is but you have to create an object for it - here the dev is just declaring it inside a struct - so how could he access it?

```
struct Uniforms
{
    enum { NumVec4 = 12 }; //Why an enum for one value?

    void init()
    {
        u_params = bgfx::createUniform("u_params", bgfx::UniformType::Vec4, NumVec4);
    }

    void submit()
    {
        bgfx::setUniform(u_params, m_params, NumVec4);
    }

    void destroy()
    {
        bgfx::destroy(u_params);
    }

    union //this union also has no object what does it mean?
    {
        struct//this struct also has no variable
        {
            union
            {
                  float m_mtx[16];
            /* 0*/ struct { float m_mtx0[4]; };
            /* 1*/ struct { float m_mtx1[4]; };
            /* 2*/ struct { float m_mtx2[4]; };
            /* 3*/ struct { float m_mtx3[4]; };
            }; //Why is this union without object?
            /* 4*/ struct { float m_glossiness, m_reflectivity, m_exposure, m_bgType; };
            /* 5*/ struct { float m_metalOrSpec, m_unused5[3]; };
            /* 6*/ struct { float m_doDiffuse, m_doSpecular, m_doDiffuseIbl, m_doSpecularIbl; };
            /* 7*/ struct { float m_cameraPos[3], m_unused7[1]; };
            /* 8*/ struct { float m_rgbDiff[4]; };
            /* 9*/ struct { float m_rgbSpec[4]; };
            /*10*/ struct { float m_lightDir[3], m_unused10[1]; };
            /*11*/ struct { float m_lightCol[3], m_unused11[1]; };
        };

        float m_params[NumVec4*4];
    }; 

    bgfx::UniformHandle u_params;
};
```

Comment: You can access members without a tag. `Uniforms().m_mtx[0] = 1.0f`

Comment: This is a trick to access the same storage via different members (e.g. a 4x4 matrix either as float[16], or as float[4][4]). I saw this e.g. in the matrix type of DirectX [XMMATRIX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/directxmath/ns-directxmath-xmmatrix). Although I like this (and used it in our own code as well) I'm not quite sure if it isn't actually Undefined Behavior. (Type punning with unions in C++ - I believe this is prohibited.)

Comment: This looks like C, not C++. The author probably doesn't realise they are different languages.

Comment: @Scheff aren't `m_mtx0` and `m_mtx1` occupying the same space here?

Comment: @Caleth Yes, you are right. Either I missed something (i.e. that was intended) or it has to be fixed to `struct { float m_mtx0[4], m_mtx1[4], m_mtx2[4], m_mtx3[4]; }`. The latter in the case that the actual intension was to have two separate representations of a 4x4 matrix as either `m_mtx[16]` or four consecutive row vectors `m_mtx0[4]` ... `m_mtx3[4]`.